# How to print a JavaScript variable within Ruby code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of radio buttons and depending on which one the user selects, a button should be displayed.

```
  <div class="cobrado-anualmente-label">
    <div class="radio_seleccion_anual_payment margin-bottom-70">
      <div class="radio billed-anual_60-radio">
        <input id="plan_pro_talent" class="radio_money_value" name="radio-anual-payment-type" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-anual_60"><span class="radio-label"></span>$60</label>
      </div>

      <div class="radio billed-anual_100-radio">
        <input id="radio-anual_100" class="radio_money_value" name="radio-anual-payment-type" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-anual_100"><span class="radio-label"></span>$100</label>
      </div>

      <div class="radio billed-anual_250-radio">
        <input id="radio-anual_250" class="radio_money_value" name="radio-anual-payment-type" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-anual_250"><span class="radio-label"></span>$250</label>
      </div>

      <div class="radio billed-anual_500-radio">
        <input id="radio-anual_500" class="radio_money_value" name="radio-anual-payment-type" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-anual_500"><span class="radio-label"></span>$500</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to generate buttons with javascript to avoid repeating the same code many times (there are a lot of buttons). Currently the buttons are handled this way in ruby:

```
  <%= button_tag "Contribute $60 a month", class: 'radio-anual_60 no_me_veo payment-action btn-plan button full-width margin-top-20', data:{ plan: @plan_pro_talent.id,key: @plan_pro_talent.name,month: @plan_pro_talent.monthly_amount,year: @plan_pro_talent.yearly_amount,plan_title: t('plan.plan3-titulo1') || '' } %>
```

buttons must be generated when a radio button option is selected

when I try to show the content of a javascript variable inside ruby "<%= %>" it doesn't allow me to access the variable. I'm getting the id of a radiobutton that has the same name as my ruby variable. I'm trying the following:

```
      <script>

        $( ".radio_money_value" ).click(function() {

         var newDiv = $("<button name='button' type='submit' class='payment-action btn-plan button full-width margin-top-20' data-plan='<%=@"'"+this.id+"'".id%>'>Contribute $250 a month</button>");

         $('.btns-stripe').append(newDiv);
        });
      </script>
```

is there any way to print the value of a javascript variable inside ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby runs on your server, JavaScript runs in the browser, at a different place, at a different time; you can't travel back in time.

But why do you even need it? You can access the JavaScript variable in... well... JavaScript.

```js
var newDiv = $("<button blah-blah-blah-blah data-plan='" + this.id + "'>blah-blah</button>")
```

Or a bit nicer (using backticks ``` `` ``` to build a template string):

```js
var newDiv = $(`<button blah-blah-blah-blah data-plan="${this.id}">blah-blah</button>`)
```

Comment: I understand. I really needed it to save some code when generating the buttons, taking the id of the selected radiobutton that would be the same name as the ruby variable so I could print the value of the ruby variable depending on the id of the radiobutton

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean there... which ruby variable?

Comment: in the controller I have a variable that contains information of a plan, then it will take the id of the radiobutton that will have the same name that the variable of my controller, this way to be able to print it inside the generator of the button.

Comment: It's still a bit confusing to me, but maybe what you want is just to check whether to the currently-generated radio button's ID is equal to the ID you are looking for? In Ruby, I mean. Not inside of any JavaScript block. (But again, I don't understand what you mean, maybe you could edit your question to explain the use case a bit better, with examples about what variable you mean, what its value could be and what end result you expect in the generated HTML output)